# How do I fix my dice-simulator in Python so it prints the amount of tries its taken before landing on a 6?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, random, while-loop

I'm using Python to simulate the throw of a dice, in which the program randomises numbers between 1-6 until it lands on the number 6. Furthermore, the program is supposed to count the number of tries it has thrown the dice before landing on a 6, and print out "It took x amount of tries to get a six." in which x is the number of tries it has thrown the dice before landing on a 6.

My code so far:

```
import random

dice = random.randint(1,6)
n = 0

while dice == 6:
    n = n + 1
    print("It took", n, "tries to get a 6.")
    break
```

For some reason, the program only prints "It took 1 try to get a 6." in the terminal and shows completely blank whenever the dice *doesn't* land on a 6. How do I get it to count the amount of attempts before landing on a 6, as well as print the amount of tries in combination with the statement print("It took", n, "amount of tries to get a 6.")?

Comment: If the initial roll is not a six, the `while` loop will never execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual pattern for repeating an action an unknown number of times is to use a `while True` loop, and then `break` out of the loop when the exit condition is satisfied.

```
rolls = 0

while True:
    die = random.randint(1, 6)
    rolls += 1

    if die == 6:
        break

print("It took", rolls, "tries to get a 6.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your `break` command into an if-statement.
In your current code it breaks within the first iteration.

As this is an assigment i dont want to tell you everything.
But that while loop condition won't get you there.
Try writing a blank while loop with a break-condition, think about it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are only defining the *dice* variable once, the program does not throw the dice again.
To achieve this, you should try something like this :

```
import random
import time

tries = 1

while True :
    dice = random.randint (1, 6)
    if dice != 6 :
        tries += 1
    else :
        print (f"It took {tries} tries to get a six.")
        break
    time.sleep (0.5)
```

(There is additional code so that the program waits for 0.5 seconds after throwing the dice each time.)